# TOML decoding in Rust?

Tags: rust, serde, toml

I'm trying to use the TOML crate to read a configuration file into a Rust struct. I was getting a consistent Serde error that seemed unrelated to my code, so I decided to try the decode examples from the TOML documentation and to my surprise, it failed to build with the exact same error.

I have filed an issue with the crate maintainer, but I have a nagging feeling I might be missing something.

The code example in question is the following:

```
//! An example showing off the usage of `Deserialize` to automatically decode
//! TOML into a Rust `struct`

#![deny(warnings)]

extern crate toml;
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

/// This is what we're going to decode into. Each field is optional, meaning
/// that it doesn't have to be present in TOML.
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    global_string: Option<String>,
    global_integer: Option<u64>,
    server: Option<ServerConfig>,
    peers: Option<Vec<PeerConfig>>,
}

/// Sub-structs are decoded from tables, so this will decode from the `[server]`
/// table.
///
/// Again, each field is optional, meaning they don't have to be present.
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct ServerConfig {
    ip: Option<String>,
    port: Option<u64>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct PeerConfig {
    ip: Option<String>,
    port: Option<u64>,
}

fn main() {
    let toml_str = r#"
        global_string = "test"
        global_integer = 5
        [server]
        ip = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 80
        [[peers]]
        ip = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 8080
        [[peers]]
        ip = "127.0.0.1"
    "#;

    let decoded: Config = toml::from_str(toml_str).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", decoded);
}
```

The error I get when building is the following:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Config: serde::de::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:51:27
   |
51 |     let decoded: Config = toml::from_str(toml_str).unwrap();
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `serde::de::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `Config`
   |
   = note: required by `toml::from_str`
```

I have tried to build it with the following toolchains:

- rustc 1.20.0-nightly (2652ce677 2017-07-17)
- rustc 1.18.0 (03fc9d622 2017-06-06)

My Cargo.toml includes the following:

```
[dependencies]
serde = "*"
serde_derive = "*"
toml = "*"
```

Am I missing something, or is the base example of decoding with this crate simply broken?

Comment: You need to include your `Cargo.toml`'s dependency section.  This is probably a version mismatch.

Comment: Thank you, @DK. just added it.

Comment: Just tried it with rustc 1.20.0 nightly of 2016-06-22, and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for trying it, @DK. Any suggestions on why it could be failing on my machine? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: And it also appears to work fine with 1.18.0 stable.

Comment: I don't know.  Have you tried in a fresh directory with no existing build artefacts or temporary files?  Maybe there's a messed-up `Cargo.lock` file.

Comment: This even runs in a [playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=95b00206bbeb7c64f5496680d0bf41c9&version=stable), so I can only imagine a corrupted target folder or a bad Cargo.lock.

Comment: Alright, that's confirmation enough for me that this is localized to my environment. Thanks for the help, guys. I'll close the issue with the crate maintainer and dig up more.

Comment: I agree with @DK. — you almost certainly have two versions of Serde and your dependency is using a different version from what you have. I've marked as a duplicate of a question that shows how to figure out exactly why.